# Get array as output in specific function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was working on my spreadsheet to keep track of my goals.
I stuck on some strange problem I can't find any fix for that, not so advanced in google sheets yet :(

I made test sheet just to show problem in isolation. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19xUOeLoXTPH3heVFMssya5sh8ZeOaIlIBpHnypaDx-A/edit?usp=sharing

I need to count amount of specific task in the arrays(weekdays) by specific value.

I have weekinfo which checks what day is on the calendar by position - in the test table I just made it equals 2
And then I have IFS function which assigns specific array by the weekinfo number - SA,SB,SC which are just arrays under variable $A$3:$A.

But for some reason any IFS - countifs, ifs etc - they can't give arrays as outcome, they just can't process them and they just give error that ifs has mismatched range sizes.

Does anyone know what might be a solution for that?

| + | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | array1 | array2 | array3 |  |  |  |
| 3 | test | 5 | test |  |  |  |
| 4 | test | 6 | test |  |  |  |
| 5 | 3 | test | test |  |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  | 0 | - should be 1 |

**formula** (`tried in Cell_E7`)

```
=LET(
SA,A3:A5,
SB,B3:B5,
SC,C3:C5,
task,"test",
weekinfo,2,
array,IFS(weekinfo=1,SA,weekinfo=2,SB,weekinfo,SC),
COUNTIF(array,task)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(
     data,A3:C5,
     task,"test",
     weekinfo,2,
     countif(choosecols(data,weekinfo),task))
```

***OR*** *with a slight modification to your formula*

```js
=LET(
SA,A3:A5,
SB,B3:B5,
SC,C3:C5,
task,"test",
weekinfo,2,
array,IF(weekinfo=1,SA,IF(weekinfo=2,SB,IF(weekinfo,SC))),
COUNTIF(array,task)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! First solution looks really clean and works perfectly, just tested it in the master function. Thank you so much!